# grails install-searchable-config

Tags: grails, searchable, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

I need to reconfigure default setting for searchable plugin. When I try to run **install-searchable-config** I get the following error:

Error I/O exception loading script [null\scripts\Init.groovy (The system cannot find the path specified)]: null\scripts\Init.groovy (The system cannot find the path specified)

Anyone knows how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the plugin before running the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plugin needs a well declared grails home but you don't have as i see from exception. you have to find and correct grails home definition (at a groovy class)